Problems to sign a simple swap in solana , using jupiter api and python
I'm making a simple script  to perform a swap in Jupiter. After  defining the public/private keys and the parameters for the transaction,  doing the request to the api and validating the last blockhash Im trying to set up the transaction this way :
#Check last block hash
latest_blockhash = client.get_latest_blockhash()
blockhash = latest_blockhash.value.blockhash

print(f'{blockhash}')

# Get the components from the original transaction
original_message = versioned_transaction.message

# Create a new MessageV0 with recent_blockhash updated
new_message = MessageV0.try_compile(
    payer=original_message.account_keys[0],  #The fee payer is the first account 
    instructions=original_message.instructions,
    address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
    recent_blockhash=(blockhash)
)

# Crear una nueva transacción con el mensaje actualizado
new_transaction = VersionedTransaction(new_message, versioned_transaction.signatures)



# Print transaction ID
print(f'Transacción enviada ID: {txid}')

I tried to use populate function and Transaction.sign in multiple ways but I think I'm not doing it correctly. I know it is probably a really simple solution but I'm learning coding just for few weeks (I'm on week7 from cs50). Any help will be really appreciated.
Thx.
